# Buffer radius around points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, buffer, arcgis-10.5, aggregate-points

I've done this tasks several times but my focus area has only been limited to the state of Mississippi.  I wish to put a 50 mile buffer radius around points that fall in the city of DC, Philadelphia PA,  and Detroit.

What coordinate system should my data frame be set to in order to accomplish this task?

In my daily operations I've only had to use NAD 83 Mississippi East or West.  I have never had to venture out in other areas of the country.

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5.

Comment: What GIS software?

Comment: I'm Sorry.  ArcGIS 10.5

Comment: Buffer tool at 10.5 supports geodesic buffers so you don't need to worry about a projected coordinate system. Look at the method parameter. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/buffer.htm